# Apply multiple different conditions to multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Given a data.table

```
dt <- data.table(
        year = c(2020, 2021, 2022), 
        b    = c(10, 20, 30), 
        c    = c(100, 200, 300)
      )
```

I would like to overwrite multiple columns each based on a different condition. Below I used a for-loop to get the basic functionality that I want.

```
cols_to_update <- c("b", "c") 
conds <- c(2020, 2022)

for ( i in seq_along(cols_to_update)) { 
    dt[year == conds[i], (cols_to_update[i]) := NaN] 
})

print(dt)
```

the final output I'm looking for should be

```
   year  b   c
1: 2020 NaN 100
2: 2021  20 200
3: 2022  30 NaN
```

I'm new to R and data.table and I'm trying to fill out my knowledge. To that end, I suspect there is a faster and more concise way to do this in data.table, probably with lapply and .SD cols, but I've had no luck. The tricky part is applying each different condition to the corresponding column.

In this case the condition is always based on the same column (i.e. year).

This code works well enough, although I am concerned that for-loops can be a bit slow relative to the efficiency of data.table (feel free to tell me thats a silly concern if thats the case).

Answer (score 1):

```r
dt[, c(cols_to_update) :=
  Map(
    function(x, yr) replace(x, year == yr, NaN),
    .SD, conds),
  .SDcols = cols_to_update ]
dt
#     year     b     c
#    <num> <num> <num>
# 1:  2020   NaN   100
# 2:  2021    20   200
# 3:  2022    30   NaN
```

If you've ever seen `lapply(.SD, fun)` in `data.table`-esque pipes, `Map(fun, .SD)` is very similar, but it allows to "zip" together other things. In this case, `Map(fun, .SD[,cols_to_update], conds)` unrolls to (effectively)

```r
fun(dt$b, conds[1])
fun(dt$c, conds[2])
```

and then stored back into `cols_to_update`.

But to be honest, this does side-step a little of `data.table`'s efficiency. If you wanted to be as fast as you could, this would likely win out (with reasonably-sized data):

```r
for (i in seq_along(cols_to_update)) {
  set(dt, i = which(dt$year == conds[i]), j = cols_to_update[i], value = NaN)
}
```